# Найдите ошибки лексической нормы

Tags: лексика

- Новое вещество является естественным, так как оно создано из смолы камфорного дерева.
- В этом отделе находятся научные монографии по физике, математике, юриспруденции.

Comment: Пока что вижу грамматические. Мало того, что ребенок сам домашние задания не делает, так еще грамотно вопрос написать не может.

Answer (score 1):

В первом предложении нужно выбрать другой член синонимического ряда: *натуральный (Новое вещество является натуральным...)*. Во втором, как верно указывает Olga, плеоназм. Уля, я надеюсь, вопрос не из домашнего задания? ;)

Answer (score 0):

Научные монографии — слово "научные" лишнее, это плеоназм